# settimeout() Exceptions Ignoring Try/Except - Python

Tags: python, sockets, settimeout, try-except

I am attempting to skip sockets that time out using a "try/except" block in Python. A snip of the block/code is below

```
s.settimeout(1)
s.sendto(NTP_QUERY, (host, port))
try:
    msg, address = s.recvfrom(1024)
    s.settimeout(None)
except:
    pass
```

My thought is that if settimeout() becomes true, it would pass from the except. Is there something I'm missing, thank you for all the help. My output is "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Why do you have the s.recvfrom twice in the snippet? Maybe it's the call before the try block that causes the exception?

Comment: That was a mis-copy, lemme fix that @MartinSeehafer

Comment: So what is happening, can you post the output?

Comment: I posted my error message at the bottom @MartinSeehafer

Comment: That error has nothing to do with timeouts, you are simply trying to reference msg before it is initialized

Comment: okay, I see that but what would cause that? is it passing past and looping around before msg is available? @yorodm

Answer (score 2):

From Python docs

> Set a timeout on blocking socket operations. The value argument can be a nonnegative floating point number expressing seconds, or None. If a non-zero value is given, subsequent socket operations will raise a timeout exception if the timeout period value has elapsed before the operation has completed. If zero is given, the socket is put in non-blocking mode. If None is given, the socket is put in blocking mode.

What that means (for your code) is:

1. Both `sendto` and `recvfrom` will launch an exception if they timeout
2. You will only handle the one from `recvfrom`

Comment: So how can I handle the sendto, maybe that's what I'm not understanding

Comment: Can you move it into the `try` clause?

Comment: if i move "s.sendto(NTP_QUERY, (host, port))" to the try clause it still just doesnt skip it throws the bound error above